# Creating rails 3 gems: Gems installing successfully, but no functionality

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm trying to create my first rails gem with jeweller - it's a very simple demo gem with just a "Tester" model and a "Frog" scaffold.

The gem packages up just fine, gem contents "testgem" confirms the desired files are packaged into the gem, and when I "bundle install" it, everything seems to go OK & the gem is in the list of installed gems.

...BUT - I'm not getting any functionality. The activerecord model isn't recognised from the command line (Command "Tester" returns "uninitialized constant Tester"), and the controllers aren't being found either, even when I manually add the resources to config/routes.

This is my first self-built gem, so I could be missing something simple. I've tried placing the necessary files in both [GEM_ROOT]/lib/app/ and [GEM_ROOT]/app/*, with gem.path set to [{lib}/**/***, {app}//*].

Any suggestions most appreciated. ;-)

Comment: Could you give us some of your code samples; it sounds like it's not really a gem problem but more of a code problem.

Comment: Hi Maran - thanks for the response. Embarrassingly enough, I figured it out a few minutes ago (answer below). Thanks for the help anyhow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ach - terribly embarrassing - 30 mins after posting I figured it out.

In case anyone else is wondering: In the gem, I wasn't directing the mygemname.rb file to the engine.rb file. In short, I needed

```
require 'mygemname/engine' if defined?(Rails)
```